# What kind of attributes does javascript get?

Tags: javascript, client

I want to get client information via javascript. However I do not know which attributes are gotten by javascript. How should I learn this?

Comment: What do you mean by "client information"? The system, or user input? As far as i know, you can read what browser, version, OS etc. But all of these can be spoofed.

Comment: I meant IP location etc. Actually I do not care about what OS user uses.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window) and [document object properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document). All client-side information is here.

Comment: and while you are at it, test by doing a `console.log(window)`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Navigator userAgent Property for that , as i understood you question

[example Navigator userAgent Property](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_nav_all)

[a very good reference for useragent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#ViewingUA)